# The VT is 0,but !dumpobj <Address> doesn.t work.I am a newer in using Visual Studio 2010+sos.dll.Who can help me?

Tags: sos, .net

!dumpvc 79b9a9ac a0a208
Name:        System.IntPtr
MethodTable: 79b9a9ac
EEClass:     798d57e0
Size:        12(0xc) bytes
File:        C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
79b5a21c  40004a9        0                  PTR  0 instance 748d5756 m_value
79b9a9ac  40004aa      b4c        System.IntPtr  1   shared   static Zero

> > Domain:Value  0015db70:NotInit  <<

!dumpobj 748d5756

Invalid object

!dumpvc 79b5a21c 748d5756
Name:        System.UIntPtr
MethodTable: 79b5a21c
EEClass:     798d8a84
Size:        12(0xc) bytes
File:        C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
79b5a21c  4000697        0                  PTR  0 instance  m_value
79b5a21c  4000698      b78       System.UIntPtr  1   shared   static Zero

> > Domain:Value  0015db70:NotInit  <<

Answer (score 2):

!dumpobj doesn't work on *what* address? Assuming you mean !dumpobj 748d5756, the problem is that !do  won't work on a Value Type.  Every object on the GC heap (ref types) has a MT (Method Table) pointer at the beginning of the object's memory.  Therefore, every object on the GC heap is self-describing.  The way !do works is that it reads the MT to determine the Type, then dumps out the object's fields.

With a Value Type, you have no MT.  A Value Type contains ONLY the fields.  Therefore, you have to use !dumpvc  .

Comment: Thank you very much!You remind me understand that the Value Type feild of a class is on the GC heap,not on the stack.So i have  to use !dumpobj to look at the Value Type feild of a class.Is that right?

Comment: That's correct.  Value type fields are stored inline with the object, whereas reference type fields only store a pointer inline with the object, but the actual reference type to which the object refers resides elsewhere on the GC heap.

Comment: Great!I think so!The question is how can i find out where the actual reference type resides.My email is 1143926160@qq.com.Will you send me a sample?Thank you greatly!

Comment: The value of the field is a pointer to the object.  In other words, it's an address.  That address is where the ref type "resides".  To inspect that ref type, pass the address to !sos.do or !sosex.mdt.